# Tensorflow MultiRNNcell

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have a following problem with MultiRNNcell, but first things first.

My data consist looks like following:

```
[[a1, b2,..., x200], [b1, b2, ..., b200], ...]
```

The relevant code is here:

```
  rows, row_size = 20, 10
  num_classes = 3
  batch_size = 128
  hidden_layer_size = 256
  n_layers = 4

  tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, rows, row_size])
  tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])

  in_x = tf.unstack(input_x, axis=1)

  network = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_layer_size, state_is_tuple=True)
                                       for _ in range(n_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

  outputs, states = rnn.dynamic_rnn(cell=network, inputs=in_x, dtype=tf.float32)
  outputs = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer["weights"]) + layer["biases"]
  ...
  ...

  x_feed = np.array(x_feed.reshape((batch_size, rows, row_size)))
  _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss_fn], feed_dict={tf_x: x_feed, tf_y: y_feed})
```

I am getting an error `ValueError: Shape (10, ?) must have rank at least 3`
 and traceback is showing on line

```
  outputs, states = rnn.dynamic_rnn(cell=network, inputs=in_x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(cell=network, inputs=x3, dtype=tf.float32)

In case, when I use `static_rnn` instead of `dynamic_rnn` everything is running fine, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. How to use `dynamic_rnn` in this case?